# MS CRM Executing a Workflow for multiple records - Behavior of execution

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I'm seeking a method to execute a workflow in Dynamics CRM, for many records, in such a way that every record chosen will start the process of the workflow only AFTER the previous record has finished processing it's workflow successfully.
I must note that I'm dealing with a workflow which has a few child workflows threaded, and therefore my request, so as not to "tangle up" while updating records in the workflow.
Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If Console application is an option, i would write one that:

- gets reference to all records that needs to be processed
- fires workflow for first one [Code to start workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309600.aspx)
- in a loop, check if workflow finished for record. You can check this by querying *asyncoperation* table, *regardingobjectid* field will have id of record that workflows was executed for
- when workflow finished for record, fire workflow for next record and wait for it to finish

Comment: Actually I am executing the workflows from a customized button (with Ribbon Workbench). Therefore a Console App is not my option :(

Comment: You are able to implement same algorithm in JavaScript. You can start workflows from JS, and use fetch XML to query asyncoperation table.

Comment: Please excuse me for my ignorance, but what do yo you mean by "custom workflow"?

Comment: I think I'll give a try to Mario's suggestion with JS. I'll report back the results. Thanx.